# Should .closest() or .currentTarget be used here?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

What I want to do is hide the covers after they are clicked.

Which of these techniques should be used to do this?

or would I use a different technique to hide the covers after they are clicked?

One uses

```
evt.target.closest('.cover').classList.add("hide");
```

And the other uses

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.add("hide");
```

**Way 1.)** https://jsfiddle.net/c5a8yepq/4/

**Html**

```
<div class="cover jacket jacket-left">
<div class="cover jacket jacket-middle">
<div class="cover jacket jacket-right">
<div class="cover jacketc>
```

**Javascript**

Adding this line:

```
evt.target.closest('.cover').classList.add("hide");
```

to this

```
 function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        initPlayer(wrapper);
        evt.target.closest('.cover').classList.add("hide");
    }
```

**Way 2.)** https://jsfiddle.net/c5a8yepq/2/

Adding just this line.

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.add("hide");
```

to this.

```
function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    show(wrapper);
    initPlayer(wrapper);
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("hide");
}
```

Comment: `.closest()` will find a `parent` element matching the selector. `.currentTarget` only matters when you delegate the event, which is not the case in your code. So `target` and `currentTarget` will be the same element. But unless you changed your HTML, your videos are in the next sibling element or a child element, not in a parent you can find with `.closest()`, since the event happens on the covers, not on the video. So no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: Would I use a different technique then to hide the covers after they are clicked? That's what I want  to do. How would you set it up?

Comment: `.closest()` only works because `evt.target` is a cover with the `.cover` class. And it is the same element as `currentTarget`, which is the same as `target`. They are ALL the same element. If you use this `.closest()` technique with a different HTML structure, it won't work. Hence using `.closest()` makes no sense at all, since you need the cover, which is the click target, and you need the next sibling. You would only need `.closest()` if the click event was on the video instead of on the cover.

Comment: What you're saying here is: evt.currentTarget.classList.add("hide"); is the code that should be used here. Doing this: evt.target.classList.add("hide"); Doesn't work in the code.

Comment: Yes. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Thank you, you as well.